# Error libapache2-mod-php5 Package ubtuntu

Tags: linux, apache2

I have the below error message in my terminal window, any one help me?

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache`enter code here`2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.30+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.20 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you are trying to manually install the package libapache2-mod-php5 from another distro (debian?) into a ubuntu system.

I would recommend installing the version from the distro's repository, maybe from a testing/unstable one if you really need a newer version, but if you need a version greater than the ones available at the official repository, then you also need to download all of it's dependencies and install them manually too.